# Excel Index & Match with differing date format

Tags: excel

I am trying to get use the Index and Match excel function to match and return dates between sets of data. However the issue i have is one set of data uses "m/dd/yyyy" format while the other uses dd/mm/yyyy" format.

See screenshot below of the 2 data to be compared and the dates:

[Data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln3qs.jpg)
[Data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsLHx.jpg)

Does anyone know how i can use this formula if i have differing set of date formats? or can suggest another formula?

Comment: Which is the formula you are talking about? Also please describe the exact problem you have. If only the date formats are different, the date values will not change. So different date formats should not be a problem. It looks in your pictures as if some of the "dates" are not dates but strings (left aligned instead of right). This you have to avoid.

Comment: Thanks Axel for highlighted the strings because it looks like that is my issue. Once i corrected to dates format it solved my issue.